# Angular не выгружает объект в форму

Tags: angular2, angular, angular-routing

Пишу CRUD приложение. Проблема с редактированием сущности. Загружаю документ на сервер с определенными атрибутами. Некоторые из них при желании можно отредактировать. При нажатии на кнопку обновить, angular не выгружает объект в форму, а берет тот единственный, что используется при загрузке страницы, что на мой взгляд тоже не совсем верно.

Т.е. при обновлении или переходе на страницу выводится не только список документов, но и как-то рандомный из них, который в последствии и можно отредактировать. Но выбрать объект для редактирования не получается. Пытался найти ошибку, но не получается, наверное что-то упускаю.

Код:

**FormEditComponent:**

```
ngOnInit() {
const documentId = localStorage.getItem('editDocumentId');

if (!documentId) {
  alert('Действие невозможно');
  this.router.navigate(['list-document']);
  return;
}

this.editForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  id: [],
  fileName: ['', Validators.required],
  fileAutor: ['', Validators.required],
  dateUploading: ['', Validators.required],
  dateLastEditing: ['', Validators.required],
  fileVersion: ['', Validators.required],
  ext: ['', Validators.required],
  filePath: ['', Validators.required],
  size: ['', Validators.required],
  typeDoc: ['', Validators.required]
});

this.documentService.getDocument(+documentId)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.editForm.setValue(data);
  });
}

onSubmit() {
this.documentService.updateDocument(this.editForm.value)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.router.navigate(['list-document']);
  },
  error => {
    alert(error);
  });
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<h2>Edit document</h2>
<form [formGroup]="editForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <label for="fileAutor">Автор файла:</label>
  <input formControlName="fileAutor" placeholder="Автор" name="fileAutor" id="fileAutor" required>
  <br>

  <label for="fileVersion">Версия файла:</label>
  <input formControlName="fileVersion" placeholder="Версия" name="fileVersion" id="fileVersion" required>
  <br>

  <label for="typeDoc">Тип файла:</label>
  <input formControlName="typeDoc" placeholder="Тип" name="typeDoc" id="typeDoc" required>
  <br>

  <button class="btn btn-success">Принять</button>
</form>
```

**ListDocumentComponent:**

```
ngOnInit() {
this.documentService.getDocuments().subscribe(data => (this.documents = data));
}

removeDocument(document: Document): void {
  this.documentService.removeDocument(document.id).subscribe(data => {
    this.documents = this.documents.filter(c => c !== document);
  })
}

editDocument(document: Document): void {
  localStorage.removeItem('editDocumentId');
  localStorage.setItem('editDocumentId', document.id.toString());
  this.router.navigate(['edit-document']);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let document of documents">
    <td class="hidden">{{document.id}}</td>
    <td>{{document.fileName}}</td>
    <td>{{document.fileAutor}}</td>
    <td>{{document.ext}}</td>
    <td>{{document.dateUploading}}</td>
    <td><button (click)="removeDocument(document)">Удалить</button></td>
    <td><button (click)="editDocument(document)">Изменить {{document.id}}</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Service:**

```
private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/documents';
private httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Run service documents');
}

getDocuments(): Observable<Document[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl).pipe(
        map(data => data as Document[])
    );
}

getDocument(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<Document>(this.baseUrl + '/' + id, { headers: this.httpHeaders });
}

createDocument(file: File): Observable<HttpEvent<{}>> {
    let formdata: FormData = new FormData();
    formdata.append('file', file);

    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/documents/add', formdata, {
        reportProgress: true,
        responseType: 'text',
    });

    return this.http.request(req);
}

removeDocument(id: number): Observable<Document> {
    return this.http.delete<Document>(this.baseUrl + '/' + id);
}

updateDocument(document: Document) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + '/' + document.id, document);
}
```

**Router:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'list-document', component: ListDocumentComponent },
    { path: 'edit-document', component: FormEditComponent },
    { path: 'upload-document', component: FormUploadComponent }
];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Comment: @overthesanity , каким-то рандомным документом заполняются поля input формы. В том то и дело, что при нажатии на кнопку изменить ничего не происходит.
Я заметил, что при загрузке документа, он не появляется в списке, т.е. фактически обновление не происходит при загрузке документа. Оно происходит только после перезагрузки страницы. Я предполагаю, что проблема в этом. В таком случае, localStorage будет заполнятся последним выбранным мной документом, и обновляться лишь при перезагрузке страницы. Возможно именно поэтому я считал, что происходит рандомная подгрузка документа. Стоит это проверить.

Comment: @overthesanity , я наверное что-то не понимаю. Сегодня проверил, все работает, но только при перезагрузке страницы. Т.е. данные не обновляются динамически. Решал различные примеры, там не было таких проблем.

Comment: я не понимаю что значит ` данные не обновляются динамически`. в localstorage не нужно хранить динамические данные, такие как айди документа, используйте параметры url

Comment: @overthesanity , параметры не использовал, буду разбираться. Но данную проблему уже решил. Заключалась она в отсутствии понимания маршрутизации. Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не совсем понятен: `Т.е. при обновлении или переходе на страницу выводится не только список документов, но и как-то рандомный из них`. Что происходит при клике на кнопку `Изменить 1`? А если `localStorage` будет пуст и перейти на `edit-document` - выходит вообще пусто будет потому что компонент ссылается на хранилище, а не параметры в URL?

Сделайте просто по человечески - ссылайтесь на параметры запроса: `path: 'edit-document/:id'`, в компоненте `FormEditComponent` инжектите `ActivatedRoute` и получайте параметры запроса через `const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')`.